# File upload functionality on node display page

Tags: 6, theming, files

I want to provide an upload button on a node display page. By clicking a button, it should be possible to upload files. Here is what I'm thinking of:

[image]

For this I am changing the `node.tpl` file.

```
 <?php //code added 
     if($node->title=='Course Materials'){?>
        <form action="" name="uploadform" >
            <input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload"/>
        </form>
    <?php  }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['upload'])){ ?> 
    <form  method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"  />
        <input type="submit" name="submit"  />
    </form> 
     <?php //end 
     }?>
```

And to save the files:

```
  if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){ 
    if(isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0){

   //$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal6upload/sites/default/files/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $node = node_load($node->nid);

        // Build the file object
        $file_obj = new stdClass();
        $file_obj->filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        **$file_obj->filepath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal6upload/sites/default/files/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];**
        $file_obj->filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_obj->uid = 1;
        $file_obj->status = FILE_STATUS_TEMPORARY;
        $file_obj->timestamp = time();
        $file_obj->list = 1;
        $file_obj->new = true;

        // Save file to files table
        drupal_write_record('files', $file_obj);

        // change file status to permanent
        file_set_status($file_obj,1);

        $node->field_test1[] = (array)$file_obj;
        node_save($node);

        drupal_goto('node/'.$node->nid);
    }
}
```

But I am facing some problem to set the filepath and file_copy instead of move_uploaded_file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to do it by creating custom module.

```
    function upload_course_form($form_id) {
    $form = array();
    $form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");
    $form['course_materials'] = array(
            '#type' => 'file',
            '#title' => t('Course Materials:'),
            '#size' => 60,
            );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
        '#weight' => 10
    );
    return $form;
}

  function upload_course_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
  $field = 'course_materials';
  $directory = file_directory_path();
  if (file_check_directory($directory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY, $field)) {
    $validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf xls html doc txt docx'));
    if ($file = file_save_upload($field, $validators, $directory)) {
      file_set_status($file, FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT);
      $form_state['storage']['file'] = $file;

    }
  }
}

function upload_course_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
print_r($form_state['storage']['file']); //see the upload file details 
//and add the code to save the node.

}
```